# Monodroid and Visual Studio. How do I use google market licensing?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.android, android-lvl

I was reading this about using google market licensing: http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/licensing.html

It says in part "Note that the LVL is not designed to be compiled separately and added to an application as a static .jar file."

Want I want to do is use it in Visual Studio 2010 with MonoDroid.

How do I do this?

It is possible because of this post: http://mono-for-android.1047100.n5.nabble.com/Android-Market-Licensing-Service-td4978581.html

But do I really need to go through all these steps?

Is there a simple way of doing this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a great story for binding to Java libraries in the current version of Mono for Android. This is something that they are improving in future releases, but it's not there yet.

In the current version you can add a JAR file or Java source file to your project and set their BuildAction to AndroidJavaSource or AndroidJavaLibrary to have them included in the build. This allows you to use JNI in order to call into the Java code from C#. It's a pretty nasty process, but it works. I have a blog post [here](http://www.gregshackles.com/2011/02/using-admob-in-a-monodroid-application/) that talks about how to set up AdMob, so you could use a similar approach with this library if you were determined.

Comment: Yes I saw that earlier and kept a bookmark as that would be handy :-)   However how do I get that JAR file for the Google Market Licensing?  It isn't part of the Android SDK when I included it as part of the extras.

Comment: Actually I might be showing my complete lack of understanding Java here. I might need to try the Java source file instead like you suggested.